# How Do you make a public TMPText unity C#

Tags: user-interface

I am new to unity and I was wondering if there is any way to call a Public TextMeshPro Because I have been trying to make a score timer Current Script For example I use
public Text ScoreText; . So is there any way to work to do something like Public Tmp_Text ScoreText; or something Like That? (Sorry I am pretty new)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish you good luck on your journey of learning unity.
There are several things you need to keep in mind to solve your problems.
Follow tutorials and learn from them.
Check [unity api](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) to get references on how specific modules/commands function.
In your case that would be [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0/manual/index.html) reference.

Here's the shortest way to do what you want:
add `using TMPro;`to the very top of your script
declare your variable `public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText`
use your variable in code to set text;

```
void AddPoints(int pointsEarned)
{
   currentScore += pointsEarned;
   scoreText.SetText(currentScore.ToString());
}
```